# How to get signed in username, email address and user group details from taskpane app

Tags: ms-word, word-addins, customtaskpane

I'm currently developing an word add-in task pane app. I am trying to retrieve the following information from the task pane app (Office Add-in) of the current signed in user information :

username, email address, user group details.

I'm trying to fetch the current signed in user information from the active directory.

**Scenario**

My document contains who can work on the sections (User1 - section 1, User2 - section 2), I need to know user_name who currently logged into the word application so that I can authenticate the users against article without asking them to log-in each time.

**Flow**

Article Creator is responsible for creating the document. This process will create word document and will be transferred to the user.

Article Admin is responsible for adding custom content controls into document where he implements controls based on current signed in user and his usergroup.

Authentication Rule is simple here. The document will load content controls according to the logged in user and the user can work on editable content set to him.